# How To Update A Label In Swift 3 With JSON Data Inside Of A Function?

Tags: swift, xcode

For some reason whenever I try to update my label with the current temperature using `self.infoLabel.text = String(temp!)` inside of the `DispatchQueue` code block, I get the following fatal error message:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure out why the code below isn't working. Thanks.

```
func getCurrentTemp(city: String){

    let weatherRequestURL = URL(string: "\(openWeatherMapBaseURL)?APPID=\(openWeatherMapAPIKey)&q=\(city)")!

    // The data task retrieves the data.


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: weatherRequestURL) { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            // Case 1: Error

            print("Error:\n\(error)")
        }
        else {

            //print("Raw data:\n\(data!)\n")
            //let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            //print("Human-readable data:\n\(dataString!)")

            do {
                // Try to convert that data into a Swift dictionary
                let weather = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                if let main = weather["main"] as? [String: Any] {

                    let temp = main["temp"] as? Double
                    print("temp\(temp!)")

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {




                        self.infoLabel.text = String(temp!)

                    })
                    //return temp as? String

                    //let temp_max = main["temp_max"] as? Double
                    //print("temp\(temp_max!)")

                    //let temp_min = main["temp_min"] as? Double
                    //print("temp\(temp_min!)")

                }
            }
            catch let jsonError as NSError {
                // An error occurred while trying to convert the data into a Swift dictionary.
                print("JSON error description: \(jsonError.description)")
            }

        }
    }

    .resume()


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found a makeshift solution to this issue (See Below). Rather than placing the code inside of the function I made, I placed it in the viewDidLoad() function. For whatever reason, `self.infoLabel?` would be nil anywhere inside of the function I made.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    print("Sucessful launched weather page.")


    let weatherRequestURL = URL(string: "\(openWeatherMapBaseURL)?APPID=\(openWeatherMapAPIKey)&q=\(city)")!

    // The data task retrieves the data.


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: weatherRequestURL) { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            // Case 1: Error

            print("Error:\n\(error)")

        }
        else {

            //print("Raw data:\n\(data!)\n")
            //let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            //print("Human-readable data:\n\(dataString!)")



            do {
                // Try to convert that data into a Swift dictionary
                let weather = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]


                if let main = weather["main"] as? [String: Any] {

                    let temp = main["temp"] as? Double
                    print("temp\(temp!)")

                    var tempInFarenheit = ((9/5)*((temp!)-273) + 32).rounded()
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {


                    self.infoLabel.text = "\(tempInFarenheit) + °"

                    })
                }

            }

            catch let jsonError as NSError {
                // An error occurred while trying to convert the data into a Swift dictionary.
                print("JSON error description: \(jsonError.description)")
            }

        }
        }

        .resume()


}
```

Although this isn't the most effective way of doing things, hopefully it can help others who are having the same problem. If I find a more effective way of doing this, I'll be sure to edit this post and include it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here: 1) either temp is nil (and it shouldn't be because you already force unwrap it in the print statement above) 2) or infoLabel is nil which happens if you broke your outlet connection.

Its easy to check; make a breakpoint above your assignment and in the debug console you can type:

```
po self.infoLabel
```

to see if its nil.  For good measure you an also check temp.

You can also add a print statement to check self.infoLabel or an assert.

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking the time to reply. I tried this and redid the outlets and it still gave me the same error message. I noticed that when anywhere inside of the function above (in the original code) it doesn't work, yet when I try to change the infoLabel's text in viewDidLoad(), it works successfully. Really stumped as to what the issue could be :-/

Comment: The call is asynchronous.  Does the label exist at the time that it returns?  And for that matter does self exist? Also to verify if its the label that is causing the crash, use optional chaining instead of the implicit unwrap: self.infoLabel?.text.  you can also print out self to see it if has a value.  You may need to take a weak or unowned reference to self and bail out if the calling view controller no longer exists when the asynchronous call completes.

Comment: Just tested it and inside of the function, using `print(self.InfoLabel?.text) ` will print nil, while using `print(self.infoLabel?.text)` in viewDidLoad() for example, returns it's proper value. Inside of the function self also does have it's expected value.